# Calendar error - double dates

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 15.04, smartphone

The calendar on my  Meizu Pro5 (not so) smart phone, running 15.04 OTA-13 has the 6th of November listed twice, Sunday and Monday, on the pull down calendar. Hence every day/date after that is wrong by one day. Any ideas on how can i can correct this would be appreciated.

Comment: Bug report filed.

Comment: For me, on my bq 4.5, it is the 30th of October, that appears to be both Sunday and Monday. December shows however again correct. -- Could you please add the link to the bug report, that you filed?

Comment: I know that a month or so ago the calendar was displaying Google Calendar events twice over two days. This has since been fixed and now single day events only show once. I wonder if this is a throw back from this fix. Have you got the Launchpad bug number that you could add FuzzyFeat, so that the people interested in this can track it? Also if we know the number, the other people it is affecting can add comments to it.

Comment: The link to the Bug Report:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1641634

Answer (score 1):

Bug fixed.  Double dates no longer a problem.